# Finding main host to m3u8 file

Tags: streaming, m3u8

I am looking for some info here. I have a list of m3u8 files that I can open in VLC but will not work in other players, I am looking to live stream one of these onto a private website (small friends website)

The file is http://190.2.145.164:8080/live/WHMCSMAG:WHMCS:10215/t4Dy2gK5u3/198570.m3u8

Any software or hints to get these to work in an iframe format? or a wordpress plugin?

Many Thanks

Marty

Comment: Works just fine for me. What happens when you try to play the video?

Comment: It works fine for me aswell on VLC. But when I try to add it to FV Player Wordpress plugin I get an error code.

Answer (score 0):

MPEG DASH streams are not supported natively on most browsers. Instead you must use a Javascript Video player which will in turn use the HTML5 Meida Source Extension (MSE) functionality and the HTML5 video tag to read the manifest file, request the segments of the video and play them back.

Examples of these types of HTML5 Javascript players include:

- https://github.com/Dash-Industry-Forum/dash.js
- https://bitmovin.com/video-player/
- https://github.com/google/shaka-player/

You can include these as HTML code or you can look for a MPEG DASH Wordpress plugin - there are several available at this time from a quick search.

Note that there is also an access issue with the video URL in your question, although this may be just a temporary problem - see below:

```js
Response
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Date: Wed, 17 Jul 2019 10:10:32 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Connection: close
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Server: nginx
```

One other thing to note just as an extra check  - if your stream is encrypted you will need to serve it as HTTPS rather than HTTP. Chrome enforces this now.